# Perceived weight in dumbbell vs. barbell

Tags: classical-mechanics, weight

I had an observation today at the gym when I was lifting weights. Lifting a dumbbell of 10 kg on each hand was as difficult for me as lifting a barbell with 5 kg on either end. It's true that the bar has some weight of its own, but still the relative ease notwithstanding the weight difference was striking and counter-intuitive for me.

I would love to know the physics involved in lifting a dumbbell and a barbell in a bicep exercise. Is there a relationship between effort, weight and angle of lifting in each of the two cases?

Comment: Perceived difficulty is not necessarily related to lever arms.  My considered opinion :-) is that "ur doin it rong" .

Comment: Most barbells bars I've seen weighed ~20 kg, so if you're putting 5 kg weights on either end, it'll weigh 30 kg total, compared to 10 kg with the dumbell.